# IEnumerable Extension

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, ienumerable

I want to make an `IEnumerable<TSource>` extension that can convert itself to a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. So far I have been trying to do it this way:

```
    public static 
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<TSource, TKey>(this 
      IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, Func<TSource, TKey> text, 
                                       Func<TSource, TKey> value)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (TSource model in enumerable)
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = ?, Value = ?});

        return selectList;
    }
```

Is this the right way to go about doing it? If so how do I draw the values from the appropriate values from the `Func<TSource, TKey>` ?

Comment: You might also consider forgetting `selectList` and doing `foreach (...) yield return new SelectListItem { ... }`, which allows deferred execution (which is more LINQ-y).

Comment: why are you not just using Select?

Comment: There are a lot of places in my code where I will be calling this and from looking at the Select function it seems that I would have to write more code then doing this way. Using Select I would have to write the code to instantiate a SelectListItem instead of just passing in the Func<>. Plus using this method the code that handles transferring to a SelectListItem is encapsulated and stored in one area of my code instead of all around my application.

Comment: I think what you really need is a factory/constructor for a SelectListItem from a TSource and your two Func<TSource, TKey>s - the projection from IEnumerable<Tsource> to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> *is* Select

Comment: What would be the advantage of that over this method? Does the .Select() function have some kind of efficiency or something over this extension method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to use the two functions you supply as parameters to extract the text and the value. Assuming both text and value are strings you don't need the `TKey` type parameter. And there is no need to create a list in the extension method. An iterator block using `yield return` is preferable and how similar extension methods in LINQ are built.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<TSource>(
  this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable,
  Func<TSource, string> text,
  Func<TSource, string> value)
{ 
  foreach (TSource model in enumerable) 
    yield return new SelectListItem { Text = text(model), Value = value(model) };
}
```

You can use it like this (you need to supply the two lambdas):

```
var selectedItems = items.ToSelecListItem(x => ..., x => ...);
```

However, you could just as well use `Enumerable.Select`:

```
var selectedItems = items.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = ..., Value = ... });
```

Comment: I use something similar occasionally, though I add 3 optional parameters (defaulted to false and 2 empty strings) and start the method with `if (includeEmptyOption) yield return new SelectListItem { Text = emptyOptionText, Value = emptyOptionValue };`  Parameters ordered as used so I can specify emptyOptionText and get default emptyOptionValue of "".

Answer (score 26):

You're re-inventing the wheel. It is what [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) intended for.

**EDIT BY @KeithS:** To answer the question, if you want this output, you can define an extension method wrapping Enumerable.Select:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<TSource>(
  this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable,
  Func<TSource, string> text,
  Func<TSource, string> value)
{ 
  return enumerable.Select(x=>new SelectListItem{Text=text(x), Value=value(x));
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You're on the right path.

Funcs are methods stored in variables, and are invoked like normal methods.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable,
    Func<TSource, TKey> text,
    Func<TSource, TKey> value)
{
    List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (TSource model in enumerable)
    {
        selectList.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = text(model),
            Value = value(model)
        });
    }

    return selectList;
}
```

If I might recommend, your Funcs should be `Func<TSource, string>` as the text and value are strings in the SelectListItem.

**Edit** Just thought of this...

Also you don't have to create an inner list but can do a *yield return* instead.  Below is my "optimized" version of your method.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable,
    Func<TSource, string> text,
    Func<TSource, string> value)
{
    foreach (TSource model in enumerable)
    {
        yield return new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = text(model),
            Value = value(model)
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the reference for *yeild return*.  It allows you to return the your results as an element in an enumerable, constructing your enumerable invisibly (to you).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: In your recommendation, did you mean `Func<TSource, string>`?

Comment: How would I call something like this? I'm still new to this.

Comment: Cool, nice use of `yield return` as well.

Comment: To invoke an extension method, reference its namespace in the *using* section where you hold your other usings.  Then you will be able to invoke the method as if it were a native method of your Enumerable.  This link should describe it better than me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx

Answer (score 4):

To me it seems like crossing a river to get water. Why not simply use select?

```
enumerable.Select(item => 
                    new SelectListItem{
                          Text = item.SomeProperty, 
                           Value item.SomeOtherProperty
                    }).ToList();
```

if you really do want a method then you could do this:

```
public static 
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<TSource, TKey>(this 
      IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, Func<TSource, TKey> text, 
                                       Func<TSource, TKey> value)
    {
        return (from item in enumerable
                select new SelectListItem{
                      Text = text(item),
                      Value = value(item)
                }).ToList();  
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A LINQ way of achieving what you want would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable, 
    Func<TSource, TKey> textSelector, 
    Func<TSource, TKey> valueSelector)
{
    return from model in enumerable
           select new SelectListItem 
           { 
               Text = textSelector(model), 
               Value = valueSelector(model) 
           };
}
```

Comment: thanks for replicating my answer. A good point bares repeating :) (to replicate the functionality you should however convert to a list or at least state why you think that's not a good idea)

Comment: It looks to me like our answers are slightly different, you convert to a list whereas I don't.  It's not necessary to convert to a list as the function declaration specifies the result is IEnumerable, by not converting to a list a caller of the function could compose the result with other LINQ operations and therefore short-circuit the full enumeration of the source (e.g. .First, .Single, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Within the body of your extension method, those two parameters are just delegates, and you can run them like any other function:

```
        selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = text(model), Value = value(model)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions work as well, but I think that the one from Martin Liversage is the best way to do it:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems = items.Select(x => 
    new SelectListItem 
        { 
            Text = x.TextProperty, 
            Value = x.ValueProperty 
        });
```